# How do I create a function that takes parameters and returned a value

Tags: python-3.x

How do I create a function that takes parameters and returned a value, and write a program to call it, passing input from the user as one of the parameters?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the SO rules and how to ask a question?

Comment: I haven't tried anything worthwhile. I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0):

First, define a function that takes two variables:

```
def func(p1, p2):
    return p1 + p2
```

Then, define your two parameters, making sure one of them is a user input:

```
p1 = input("p1?")
p2 = "5"
```

Finally, call the function:

```
func(p1, p2)
```